# C - Dynamic array of integers error (Code:Blocks / Visual Studio)

Tags: c, visual-studio, constants, codeblocks, dynamic-arrays

Can someone explain why am I getting error running this code in Visual Studio 17, but not in Code:Blocks?

```
    int n,m;
    int main (){
    printf("n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("m");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    int tab[n][m];    // Return error
    }
```

In VS I'm getting a 'constant value error' asking me to replace the [n] and [m] integers with constant values, yet in Code:Blocks I get no errors at all. 
It works in VS when I use the malloc() function to allocate mememory for 'tab' first, but I was wondering why I doesn't work the same way as in Code:Blocks.

Comment: Microsoft still doesn't support C99?

Comment: The issue is not about VS vs CodeBlocks, it is about which compiler is used by the two programs and which options are passed to it. Most likely the CodeBlocks compiler is gcc, and is run with the `-std=c99` option to enable the `c99` standard specifications, while VS uses `-std=c89` or just another compiler which is following the c89 standard. In the c89 standard, dynamic size declarations are not allowed, and that's why you get the error.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli , thank you. Is there any way I can overrule it? Or just accept that every time I'll be dealing with dynamic arrays I would have to allocate memory in the first place?

Comment: @Michał I personally never used VS so I cannot say for sure, but you can search on Google "visual studio enable c99" or something along the lines of that. Most of the answers I've searched a few minutes ago seem to talk about needing VS >= 2013 and using the C++ compiler. Not much more I can help you with, sorry. Google is your best friend!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are declaring a `variable-length array`. This is a feature of the `C` language in codeblocks with some compilers which support it as an extension. `Visual Studio` does not;

```
int n,m;
int main (){
printf("n");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("m");
scanf("%d", &m);
int *tab[m]; 
for (i=0; i<m; i++) 
     tab[i] = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```